# Text mining collocations package in R

Tags: r, text-mining

Hi is there a package in R that helps in finding cooccurance of word similar to collocations in python NLTK pakage.Like given a corpus list all the cooccurance  word pairs

Answer (score 7):

Yes, broadly speaking you would need:

- The `tm` package that is framework for text mining
- The `SnowballC` for stemming
- `qdap` and `qdapDictionaries` for the quantitative discourse analysis

I would suggest that you refer to an excellent text [Hands-On Data Science with R](http://onepager.togaware.com/TextMiningO.pdf) by Graham Williams that explains how those tools can be used in practice.